# PHP / MySQL results repeating

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I'm having a problem with PHP. I want the following code to only show one result from the databse - the one that matches the siteID field. But instead it is returning all of the results from the database.

```
<?php                    
$siteID = $_GET['siteID']; 
include 'connect.php';                      
$sql = "SELECT id, siteID,name,description,skills,extra1,extra2 FROM folio";   
$queryresult = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryresult)) {
$id = $row['id'];
$siteID = $row['siteID'];
$name = $row['name'];
$description = $row['description'];
$skills = $row['skills'];
$extra1 = $row['extra1'];
$extra2 = $row['extra2'];

echo "<div id='title'>       
<h5>$name</h5>
</div>

<div id='holder'>
    <div id='blogleft'>
</div>

<div id='blogright'>
    <p>Archive / Calendar<br /><br /> Add some sort of calendar or archive here; for previous blog posts.</p>
</div>
</div>";
}
?>
```

the url ends with "`/work.php?siteID=pluggedin`"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a WHERE clause.

```
$sql = "SELECT id, siteID, name, description, skills, extra1, extra2 FROM folio WHERE siteID='".$siteID."'";
```

Although i don't recommend this at all. Look up SQL injection if you don't know what I'm talking about. I would do a PDO statement instead.

Something like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM folio WHERE siteID=:siteid";
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->bindParam(':siteid', $siteid, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->execute();
$result = $sth->fetchAll();
print_r($result);
```

You can also do:

```
$result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

which gives you an array with column names, similar to mysql_fetch_assoc, this will retrieve the next row, again similar to mysql_fetch_assoc.

Comment: @user1039878 I updated my answer with what you are most likely looking for.

Comment: Cheers Matt, appreciate the help.

Comment: To learn more about the dangers of SQL injection, you can start here: http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php --also, it would be nice if you can move into stored procedure programming as well

Answer (score 0):

You didnt used any where condition in your query.

Try this

```
   $sql = "SELECT id, siteID, name, description, skills, extra1, extra2 FROM folio WHERE siteID='".(int)$_GET['siteID']."' ";
```

Comment: why do you use single quote ('') for `int` type value?

Comment: @Arif for the consistency, I suppose. though, siteid turned to be a string.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT 
            id, 
            siteID, 
            name, 
            description, 
            skills, 
            extra1, 
            extra2 
        FROM folio 
        where siteID = $siteID";
```

You just miss the `where` clause.

Answer (score -1):

That's because you are selecting all your records in your table ... add a [LIMIT clause](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) to your query